# How to move details columns between their parent groups in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I'm trying to put together a report in SSRS that displays the "details" column in between the columns that are part of its parent groups.

In the example below, the `po number` column has parent groups of `asn`, `container trailer`, and `lot arrival datetime`.

I can get it to look like this by dragging the `po number` field into a table on the design canvas, and then adding parent groups `lot arrival datetime`, `container trailer`, and `asn`:

grouping

[image]

But I want it to look like this:

desired grouping

[image]

How do I move the details column, `po number`, to be between two columns that are part of parent groups?

Comment: you just want to change the position of po number column?

Comment: @bmsqldev Yes but need to ensure the grouping stays intact.  I looked at the report code XML but looks like the grouped columns are separate from the `po number` column so it doesn't appear to be a matter of copying/pasting the columns.

Comment: Did you find any solution?